# GoogleMap: Edit markers and polylines

Tags: android, hashmap, google-maps-api-2

I have a long, variable list of `Marker`s and `Polyline`s I'm getting from my server. In some conditions, the `Marker`s have to change their icons, and the `Polyline`s have to change their colors.

My objects have ids, so I should be able to know which polyline / marker I have to update. However, Markers and Polylines do not have `setId()` or `getId()` methods, and they are updated (and added) dynamically when the server requests it.

I've thought of using a `HashMap<Integer, Marker>` and a `HashMap<Integer, Polyline>` in order to know which items I should remove and then add. I've thought of this:

- I recieve an item. I get its id.
- I query the correct `HashMap` for an item with the same Id.
- If the HashMap does not return null, I call `Marker.remove()` or `Polyline.remove()`, and then I remove the item from the `HashMap`
- Now `hashMap.get(id)` should return null no matter what, so I draw the `Polyline` / `Marker` in the `GoogleMap` add the item to the `HashMap`.

But before I start implementing this, I would like to know if there's any way of doing this that does not involve using giant `HashMap`s.

Is there any alternative way of achieving this behavior without using `HashMap`s, `SparseArray`s or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used just once the Google Map API for Android, but I'm quite sure, after checking the documention related to it, that this should be possible adding some Listeners.

Could you provide in which conditions should the information change? For example, if the marker changes when you click it, you could use GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener

Anyway, if you have the marker's reference, with a Java variable, cannot you change that information? Or simply, cannot you clear the markers over the map and add them again when this "conditions" you talk about happen? You won't have the same markers, but the result will be the same. I'm afraid you cannot modify the markers when they are already attached to the map, but you could try it.

Comment: When the server decides it (and it decides it fairly often), information is sent via a socket, and the client has to update the UI. Also, sometimes the app also asks the server for info (either because it needs to update because the info is way too old, or because the user requests it), we have to update marker icons and polyline colors.

Clearing the markers and repainting them again is what I'm doing. It isn't a good solution, it's laggy and the UI feels sloppy and slow. Not a good idea when you have over 500 objects represented on the map.

Comment: Did you try the other approach that I told you? Either using a Listener (it might be possible some of the Listeners could be useful for your needs) either the references to the markers? I cannot remember right now if you can or cannot edit a marker and see the effects in the map...

Comment: I was checking your problem, and the only thing you can do is what you are doing now. You have to clear the markers and repaint them. So my suggestion is to decrease the number of update requests, or increase the time between update requests.
I guess that you are using an ItemizedOverlay where you attach all your Overlays, isn't it?

Comment: Since I started using API V2, I haven't used any Overlays at all. GoogleMap.addMarker(), GoogleMap.addPolyline() and GoogleMap.addPolygon() is all I have ever needed.

Comment: Could you try with the Overlays? I don't know what's going on under these methods you talk about, but I'm pretty sure, that the Overlay "system", is quite effective. I was using, at the beginning, an Overlay per marker, and this was painful with the redrawing and Android memory. Attaching all the markers to one simple Overlay, worked really good. I'm using a different Map API, but I draw thousands of markers over the map, and it takes less than a second to do it...I cannot imagine that you have more requirements than I do, so it has to be an effective way with Google Map API...

Comment: Yeah. Actually, Google Maps V2 API does not support overlays. However, the addMarker and addPolyline methods return Marker and Polyline objects that you can cache and call remove() on if needed. So no big deal, I implemented my SparseArray cache and everything is going fine.

Comment: Perfect! So you just have to change the markers that change :D

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda ;-)